# Getting WrongTYpeOfReturnValue for a test that has two When statements

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have two whens:

```
when(mock.returnList()).thenReturn(<List>);
when(injectedMock.returnFloat()).thenReturn(float);
```

The error is saying that the returnList() function cannot return a float. I don't know what exactly is causing this since returnList() is returning a list.

The Code:

```
@Mock
private Row row;

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

@Test
public void getTest() {

RowMock rowMock = new RowMock(); 
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();

rowMock.setBrandCode("YYY");
rowMock.setName("NAME");
rowMock.setDataType(Float.class);
rowMock.setcValue("cValue");
rowMock.setNumberValue(randomNumber);
rowMock.setDescription("Description");

rows.add(rowMock);

when(repo.findByName(Mockito.<String>anyList())).thenReturn(rows);
when(service.getByName("NAME", "YYY", Float.class)).thenReturn(randomNumber);        

}
```

RowMock is a mock class I created that implements the Row class so I could return List from repo.findByName().

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: Based on the question asked,it is unclear to know the cause. Could you please provide more details i.e. the code,

Comment: just added the test code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock a normal object:

```
@InjectMocks
private Service service;

...

when(service.getByName("NAME", "YYY", Float.class)).thenReturn(randomNumber);
```

You cannot do that. If you have to mock the class under test then use spying:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private Service service;
```

and use reversed stubbing:

```
doReturn(randomNumber).when(service).getByName(...);
```

Comment: If the class is unit testing `Service` I believe OP is misunderstanding something regarding stubbing dependencies. Having to use a Spy is usually an indication of code smells.

Comment: Correct, that is why i have ephasised: "If you have to mock the class under test"

Comment: This removes the error but what I did find was I should just be calling the service and not using when().then() on the service.